# Mercurial - How did my commit get split off (see pic)?

Tags: version-control, configuration, mercurial, tortoisehg

What's going on with the line that split out on it's own?  I did a commit and then I did a pull for the repository and then an update.

What caused this?

How do I get that split part back into the main line?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The split is a new branch.  You can merge it back to the trunk if you like, though beware of borked code.  To do the merge, select the tip of the new branch, bring up the context menu, and select Merge With.  It will merge with whatever Rev is currently tagged as `tip`.

Answer (score 4):

Michal has your "how to fix" -- pick his answer --, but here's why it happened: Before committing you had not updated to  the tip revision.  If you do a `hg pull` your current-revision (as reported by `hg parents`) isn't updated to `tip`.  You need to `hg update tip` or `pull -u` to make that happen.  New commits always have a parent revision of your current `hg parents` output, not necessarily `tip`.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.  So I should always do a pull before doing a commit.

Comment: Yeah, do a pull and an update and if necessary a merge.  The usual work cycle is: while (true) { code; commit; pull; update; merge; if (buildable && tests_pass) { push } }.  I repeat that pattern multiple times day during busy periods.